# How to plot the different graphs by stcurve in one chart in Stata?

Tags: stata

I am using `stcurve` in Stata to plot survival probability. I need to plot the graph for all data and then for specific variables. I can generate the graphs in two different charts, but I need to have all three lines together in one chart.

I have tried the `addplot()` option but I get the error that `stcurve` is not a `twoway` graph. Do you have any idea how to do this?

This is the code that I have used which generates the graphs in two different charts separately:

```
stcurve, survival   graphregion(lcolor(white)  ilcolor(white)    ifcolor(white) )  plotregion( lcolor(black))  title("Survival Function", size(vlarge))  ytitle("Survival probabilities", size(large))  xtitle("Time", size(large))  xlabel(,labsize(medium))  ylabel(,labsize(medium))

stcurve, survival at1( def=0) at2( def=1) graphregion(lcolor(white) ilcolor(white)   ifcolor(white) )  plotregion( lcolor(black)) legend(label(1 "X Firms") label(2 "Y Firms"))  legend(size(large))  lwidth(thin thick)  title("Survival Function", size(vlarge))  ytitle("Survival probabilities", size(large))  xtitle("Time", size(large))  xlabel(,labsize(medium))  ylabel(,labsize(medium))
```

Comment: You might want to check [list 1](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2004-04/msg00139.html) and [list 2](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2009-01/msg00483.html) and [list 3](http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1048-how-to-overlay-survival-curve-of-the-source-population). Note that `addplot()` is to be used only with "any subcommand of `graph twoway`", so it won't work with another call to `stcurve`.

Comment: Please clarify if you want: 1) the two graphs  side-by-side in a single combined graph;  or 2) two different curves in a single graph with one Y (Survival Proportion) axis  and one X (Time) axis.

Comment: Hi Steve, What I want is number 2, i.e. all curves in one graph with the same Y and X axis. Actually, I need three curves in one graph, one for the whole data, and another two separated by def=0 and def=1. At the moment, using the code above, I can generate the one for the whole data in one graph and the next two in another graph. But I need all three in one graph! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood correctly what you want. It would have been useful if you had added the `stset` and `stcox` code necessary before running `stcurve`.

If the Kaplan-Meier hazard graph is identical to your first `stcurve, survival` you can try a dirty fix by generating a variable e.g.

`sts gen s2=s` after running `stset`

then plotting it as a line against your time variable. i.e. adding this to the end of the second graph:

```
addplot(line s2 your_timevar, sort c(J) title("Survival probabilities"))
```

The equality of KM hazard and Cox hazard only holds if the first graph does not have any more predictors than `failvar` in the `stset`. So if you ran `stcox, estimate` after `stset timevar, failure(failvar) id(idvar)` it works, but if you have more variables in the `stcox` call  this will not give you the correct plot.

edit: 
As the above quick solution does not work, there is another dirty workaround: save the results from `stcurve` in a file (option `outfile`), then plot the "new" data as `twoway` graphs. Something like this:

```
stcurve, survival name("surv1") outfile(stcurve1.dta, replace)
stcurve, survival name("surv2") at1( def=0) at2( def=1) outfile(stcure2.dta, replace)

use stcurve1.dta, clear
rename surv1 surv1_A 
rename _t _tA
append using stcurve2.dta
twoway line surv1 _t, sort || line surv1_A _tA, sort
```

I do not know if this will work with your data: it may be that you need to manipulate the new variables in the outfiles in some way to get the desired results, and you need to add the options you want to the `twoway` graphs. There surely are many better and easier ways of plotting this when you have the data for the graphs in separate datafiles, but this is the first solution that sprang to mind.

Comment: Thanks German for the answer. I tried it but it did not work. This is what I use for the survival estimation if it helps!:                                                                              gen cn= company_number //
xtset cn time_id //
gen k=time_id-1 //
gen j=time_id //
stset j, failure( def==1) origin(k) id(cn) //
stcox Var1 Var2 Var3, nohr nolog vce(robust)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I could perfectly have the three curves altogether in a graph. I could also add the options, but the lwidth and lpattern don't work. Is it really the case?

Comment: The [list1](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2004-04/msg00139.html) link that Roberto Ferrer gave is also a solution (by May Bogges).

Comment: lwidth and lpattern work on `twoway` graphs. I suspect you are writing it as you would do in `stcurve`, not as is correct on `twoway`. Add the option `connect (lwidth(thin) lpattern(solid))` to the code.

something like this:
`twoway line surv1 _t, sort c(lw(thin) lp(solid)) || line surv1_A _tA, sort c(lw(thick) lp(dash))`

Comment: Perfect, it's working now. You were right about my mistake German.