# Calculating difference in survival functions at time t in Stata

Tags: stata

I am estimating a Cox model in Stata using `stcox`.  I estimate the model at

```
stcox treat x1 x2 x3
```

I can then use the `stcurve` command to plot the survival function for treatment and control groups, with the `x1`, `x2` and `x3` variables set at their means by doing

```
stcurve, survival at1(treat=0) at2(treat=1)
```

However, I would also like to calculate the difference in the survival function at specific, discrete points in time.  For instance, I'd like to know the probability of survival to 1 year for treated and control groups, with `x`'s set to their means.  I think I might be able to do this with the `sts generate` command and its `adjustfor` option, but I am a little confused about whether I should use `by` or `strata` when using `sts generate` and I'm also not sure how to hold the control variables at their means rather than at 0.  The Stata help pages suggest I can center the values of the controls by subtracting `x1`'s mean from `x1`, but I am not sure if I am reading this correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote an answer to a similar question which might be useful [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043237/how-to-plot-the-different-graphs-by-stcurve-in-one-chart-in-stata/28063541#28063541), but do not have enough reputation to answer this as a comment, so here goes:

You can do `stcox treat x1 x2 x3` and `stcurve, survival at1(treat=0) at2(treat=1) outfile(stcurve.dta)`. In the file **stcurve.dta** you will have the data that produced the graph, which could be used for you purposes of looking up specific timepoints (not terribly familiar with `stcox` and `stcurve` but think it should work).

regarding `sts generate`: I should use `by(treat)` if you only want to see the difference between treatment groups. However, using `by` vs `strata` is more of a statistical question which I am not qualified to answer, You are reading the help pages correctly, but cannot say if this approach makes statistical sense and do not know if `sts generate` allows for several variables in `adjustfor`. My suggestion is just try it and see if it works. Make your own mean variable and use that to make a new `x` to use in `sts generate` if the data you need is not in **stcurve.dta**. Something like this:

```
local varlist = x1 x2 x3
foreach x in `varlist' {
egen mean_`x'=mean(`x') 
gen adj_`x'=`x' - mean_`x'
}
*  
sts generate survival=s, by(treat) adjustfor(adj_x1)
```

then you will have your data in the variable called survival. another possibility is using `sts list by(treat) adjustfor(adj_x1) compare` instead of `sts generate`

Comment: To subtract means, run `summarize` and then subtract `r(mean)`. You don't need to create new variables holding just the means.

Comment: good point. Its an old habit to generate means as variables since I usually make them by many different groups but completely unnecessary here.